# OnClick function not working even after enabling button in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have an input field and submit button but the button remains disabled till the input is empty. Otherwise it should be enabled. However, even after the button is enabled, the onclick function does not seem to work. How do I fix this?

The buttons are:

```
<button className="New_Project_Modal_Button">Cancel</button>
<button className="New_Project_Modal_Button" 
          disabled={true} 
          style={{ opacity: 0.7,}}
          onClick={() => { this.createNewProject()}}>
      Create
</button>
```

The input is:

```
<input id="New_Project_Modal_Name_Input"
      onChange={this.handleProjectNameChange}
      placeholder="Project Name"
 />
```

and function is:

```
handleProjectNameChange = (event) => {
    const createButton = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "New_Project_Modal_Button"
    )[1];

    if (event.target.value) {
      createButton.disabled = false;
      createButton.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      createButton.disabled = true;
      createButton.style.opacity = 0.7;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your button is always disabled as in your button, the disabled property is always true. You should use state for manipulation instead.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      disabled: true
    };
  }
  handleProjectNameChange = (event) => {
    const createButton = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "New_Project_Modal_Button"
    )[1];

    if (event.target.value) {
      this.setState({ disabled: false });
      createButton.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      this.setState({ disabled: true });
      createButton.style.opacity = 0.7;
    }
  };

  createNewProject = () => {
    alert("Clicked"); //whatever your function is
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id="New_Project_Modal_Name_Input"
          onChange={this.handleProjectNameChange}
          placeholder="Project Name"
        />

        <button className="New_Project_Modal_Button">Cancel</button>
        <button
          className="New_Project_Modal_Button"
          disabled={this.state.disabled}
          style={{ opacity: 0.7 }}
          onClick={() => {
            this.createNewProject();
          }}
        >
          Create
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle disable boolean using state , initially it should be set to `true` then based on event value disabled is set to `false`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDisabled: true,
    };
  }
```

```
 handleProjectNameChange = (event) => {
    const createButton = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "New_Project_Modal_Button"
    )[1];
    if (event.target.value) {
      this.setState({ isDisabled: false }); 
      createButton.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      this.setState({ isDisabled: true });
      createButton.style.opacity = 0.7;
    }
  };
```

```
          <button
          className="New_Project_Modal_Button"
          disabled={this.state.isDisabled} //initiall is set to true
          style={{ opacity: 0.7 }}
          onClick={() => {
            this.createNewProject();
          }}
        >
          Create
        </button>
```

```
          <input
          id="New_Project_Modal_Name_Input"
          onChange={this.handleProjectNameChange}
          placeholder="Project Name"
        />
```